# Why is this anti-aliasing artefact happening?

Tags: antialiasing

Shown below is a render of a model of mine.

[image: enter picture description here]

<sup>Larger version [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N315B.png)</sup>

As you can see in the circled portions, the anti-aliasing is pretty bad. How do I improve it?

I've tried increasing the samples per pixel and the sample width, but neither seem to help it. Is there any other way to correct it?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the render panel: http://i.stack.imgur.com/SHZqf.png . File is [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0E54rvqJEY-OHJaRF9EWUtLOVU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Changing the quality lower makes it slightly better, but it is still noticeable and the rest of the image's quality goes down.

Comment: just saw the link, remember you can shift+b to render only a small portion ..for debugging. am checking now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have transparency on the Island material, switching it off seems to do the trick,

[image]

Comment: This works. I'm not sure how the transparency got turned on.

Comment: cool! sometimes accidental keystrokes.. who knows.